# Reading stock data using pandas datareader

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import numpy as np
import datetime



start = datetime.datetime(2006, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)




df = data.DataReader(['BAC', 'C', 'GS', 'JPM', 'MS', 'WFC'],'google', start, end)
```

I am using Datarader to read stock market data but am getting below error.
Any info on how this issue is getting generated would be helpful. I am using Python 3.6

> ```
> return b.decode(encoding or 'utf-8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 29145: invalid continuation
> ```
>
> byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google removed support for its finance APIs in early 2018. As such, the Google reader has been deprecated for the next Pandas Datareader version.

It's advisable to use other readers (such as Quandl, AlphaVantage, or IEX) to obtain equities data. See the Pandas Datareader [documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more information.